# View does not update on object update

Tags: angular, typescript

The acceptRequest(commissioner function in child.component sets commissioner.requestAccepted to false, and then returns the updated commissioner object.

What I want to accomplish is that the button is removed from the view after I update the object, but this is not happening. I have to refresh the page to make the button disappear.

parent.component.ts

```
commissioners: any[];

ngOnInit() {
    this.usersService.getCommissioners().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.commissioners = res.commissioners;
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    )
  }
```

parent.component.html

```
<child-list *ngIf="commissioners" [commissioners]="commissioners"></child-list>
```

child.component.ts

```
  @Input() commissioners: any[];

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChange) {
    this.commissioners = changes['commissioners'].currentValue;
  }

  acceptRequest(commissionerId) {
    this.usersService.acceptRequest(commissionerId)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          for (let commissioner of this.commissioners) {
            if (commissioner._id == res._id) {
              console.log(commissioner); //old object (requestAccepted: false)
              commissioner = res;
              console.log(commissioner); //new object (requestAccepted: true)
              break;
            }
          }
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
  }
```

child.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let commissioner of commissioners">
   <button *ngIf="!commissioner.requestAccepted" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="acceptRequest(commissioner._id)">Accept</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>My guess is that your `if` statement is false. Well, it is false, but it could very well be the solution to the issue you are facing. You should use `===`:</strike>

Another point is that you are not updating the array itself, but just changing the reference to a local variable, which makes your code so much easier:

```
res => {
    for(let i = 0, l = this.commissioners.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (this.commissioners[i]._id === res._id) {
            this.commissioners[i] = res;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, you changed it to two `==` now! :D

Comment: The change of for loop fixed my problem, thank you very much :)